# How to add mean line in a boxplot made with highcharter?

Tags: javascript, r, plot, highcharts

I'm trying to add the average (mean) in the tooltip on the boxplot made with {highcharter} the mean. By default, it displays : min, max, Q1, Q3 and median.
I already asked SO here:
[How to add mean in a boxplot made with highcharter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67120145/how-to-add-mean-in-a-boxplot-made-with-highcharter)

But now I would like to display the mean with a line !
I saw this in JS :
https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/95104988.html

And I think I'm closed with {highcharter} in my example below.

Many thanks in advance !

```
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter) 

data(pokemon) 

pokemon_graph <- pokemon %>% 
  group_by(type_1) %>% 
  mutate(moyenne = round(mean(height,na.rm = T)),1) %>% 
  ungroup()

dat <- data_to_boxplot(pokemon_graph, height, type_1, name = "height in meters")

highchart() %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
  hc_add_series_list(dat) %>% 
  hc_tooltip(useHTML = TRUE, headerFormat = "<strong>mon graph</strong><br/>",
             pointFormat = paste0("Min: {point.low}<br/>
                                   Q1: {point.q1}<br/>
                                   Median: {point.median}<br/>
                                   Q3: {point.q3}<br/>
                                   Max: {point.high}<br/>
                                   Mean: {point.moyenne}<br/>"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Hacking Highcharter](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/07/hacking-highcharter-observations-per-group-in-boxplots/) gives a possible solution.

You could create a custom `get_box_values` function with mean calculation :

```
get_box_values <- function(x) {
  boxplot.stats(x)$stats %>% t() %>% cbind(mean(x)) %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
    setNames(c("low", "q1", "median", "q3", "high", "mean"))
}
```

You can then assign this function in the `highcharter` namespace and use its new calculations:

```
library(dplyr)
library(highcharter) 

data(pokemon) 

get_box_values <- function(x) {
  boxplot.stats(x)$stats %>% t() %>% cbind(mean(x)) %>% as.data.frame() %>% 
    setNames(c("low", "q1", "median", "q3", "high", "mean"))
}

assignInNamespace("get_box_values", get_box_values, ns="highcharter")

dat <- data_to_boxplot(data = pokemon, height, type_1, name = "height in meters")

highchart() %>%
  hc_xAxis(type = "category") %>%
  hc_add_series_list(dat) %>% 
  hc_tooltip(useHTML = TRUE, headerFormat = "<strong>mon graph</strong><br/>",
             pointFormat = paste0("Min: {point.low}<br/>
                                   Q1: {point.q1}<br/>
                                   Median: {point.median}<br/>
                                   Q3: {point.q3}<br/>
                                   Max: {point.high}<br/>
                                   Mean: {point.mean}<br/>"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can wrap JS code and operate on a dedicated Highcharts API that enables formatting the tooltip: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Here you can find an article that describes how this can be done in R:
https://www.highcharts.com/blog/tutorials/working-with-highcharts-javascript-syntax-in-r/?fbclid=IwAR3etap9WisQW43uzG7epgCWfcwy6oWBisUVOwzlADsKKb2mOO_XXojp948

Comment: Ok thanks i will watch but i thought someone had done it before me