# Redefining R's nnet::multinom predict.multinom predict method to support type="link"

Tags: r, multinomial, emmeans, nnet, marginal-effects

I would like to have R's `nnet::multinom` function being supported by the new `marginaleffects` package, but `marginaleffects::predictions()` relies on the `predict()` methods supplied by the modeling packages to compute predicted values on both the response and link scale. In the case of `nnet::multinom`, however, the `predict()` method supplied by `nnet` does not support predictions on the link scale - it only supports `type="probs"` or `type="class"`, https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/marginaleffects/issues/404. So I would like to redefine the `nnet::multinom` `predict.multinom` method so that it would also support `type="link"` (in the original namespace of that package, so that also the `marginaleffects` package would see it as having been redefined). Is there any way to accomplish this?

For reference, the `predict.multinom` method (https://github.com/cran/nnet/blob/master/R/multinom.R) now looks like

```
predict.multinom <- function(object, newdata, type=c("class","probs"), ...)
{
    if(!inherits(object, "multinom")) stop("not a \"multinom\" fit")
    type <- match.arg(type)
    if(missing(newdata)) Y <- fitted(object)
    else {
        newdata <- as.data.frame(newdata)
        rn <- row.names(newdata)
        Terms <- delete.response(object$terms)
        m <- model.frame(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.omit,
                         xlev = object$xlevels)
        if (!is.null(cl <- attr(Terms, "dataClasses")))
            .checkMFClasses(cl, m)
        keep <- match(row.names(m), rn)
        X <- model.matrix(Terms, m, contrasts = object$contrasts)
        Y1 <- predict.nnet(object, X)
        Y <- matrix(NA, nrow(newdata), ncol(Y1),
                    dimnames = list(rn, colnames(Y1)))
        Y[keep, ] <- Y1
    }
    switch(type, class={
        if(length(object$lev) > 2L)
            Y <- factor(max.col(Y), levels=seq_along(object$lev),
                        labels=object$lev)
        if(length(object$lev) == 2L)
            Y <- factor(1 + (Y > 0.5), levels=1L:2L, labels=object$lev)
        if(length(object$lev) == 0L)
            Y <- factor(max.col(Y), levels=seq_along(object$lab),
                        labels=object$lab)
    }, probs={})
    drop(Y)
}
```

with `predict.nnet` (https://github.com/cran/nnet/blob/master/R/nnet.R) being given by

```
predict.nnet <- function(object, newdata, type=c("raw","class"), ...)
{
    if(!inherits(object, "nnet")) stop("object not of class \"nnet\"")
    type <- match.arg(type)
    if(missing(newdata)) z <- fitted(object)
    else {
        if(inherits(object, "nnet.formula")) { #
            ## formula fit
            newdata <- as.data.frame(newdata)
            rn <- row.names(newdata)
            ## work hard to predict NA for rows with missing data
            Terms <- delete.response(object$terms)
            m <- model.frame(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.omit,
                             xlev = object$xlevels)
            if (!is.null(cl <- attr(Terms, "dataClasses")))
                .checkMFClasses(cl, m)
            keep <- match(row.names(m), rn)
            x <- model.matrix(Terms, m, contrasts = object$contrasts)
            xint <- match("(Intercept)", colnames(x), nomatch=0L)
            if(xint > 0L) x <- x[, -xint, drop=FALSE] # Bias term is used for intercepts
        } else {
            ## matrix ...  fit
            if(is.null(dim(newdata)))
                dim(newdata) <- c(1L, length(newdata)) # a row vector
            x <- as.matrix(newdata)     # to cope with dataframes
            if(any(is.na(x))) stop("missing values in 'x'")
            keep <- 1L:nrow(x)
            rn <- rownames(x)
        }
        ntr <- nrow(x)
        nout <- object$n[3L]
        .C(VR_set_net,
           as.integer(object$n), as.integer(object$nconn),
           as.integer(object$conn), rep(0.0, length(object$wts)),
           as.integer(object$nsunits), as.integer(0L),
           as.integer(object$softmax), as.integer(object$censored))
        z <- matrix(NA, nrow(newdata), nout,
                    dimnames = list(rn, dimnames(object$fitted.values)[[2L]]))
        z[keep, ] <- matrix(.C(VR_nntest,
                               as.integer(ntr),
                               as.double(x),
                               tclass = double(ntr*nout),
                               as.double(object$wts)
                               )$tclass, ntr, nout)
        .C(VR_unset_net)
    }
    switch(type, raw = z,
           class = {
               if(is.null(object$lev)) stop("inappropriate fit for class")
               if(ncol(z) > 1L) object$lev[max.col(z)]
               else object$lev[1L + (z > 0.5)]
           })
}
```

I was hoping I could perhaps overwrite the `predict.multinom` function by the `predict.mblogit` function (https://github.com/melff/mclogit/blob/master/pkg/R/mblogit.R), or something close to it (probably some minor edits needed, due to the mblogit and nnet objects being structured slightly differently) :

```
predict.mblogit <- function(object, newdata=NULL,type=c("link","response"),se.fit=FALSE,...){
  
  type <- match.arg(type)
  mt <- terms(object)
  rhs <- delete.response(mt)
  if(missing(newdata)){
    m <- object$model
    na.act <- object$na.action
  }
  else{
    m <- model.frame(rhs,data=newdata,na.action=na.exclude)
    na.act <- attr(m,"na.action")
  }
  X <- model.matrix(rhs,m,
                    contrasts.arg=object$contrasts,
                    xlev=object$xlevels
  )
  rn <- rownames(X)
  D <- object$D
  XD <- X%x%D
  rspmat <- function(x){
    y <- t(matrix(x,nrow=nrow(D)))
    colnames(y) <- rownames(D)
    y
  }
  
  eta <- c(XD %*% coef(object))
  eta <- rspmat(eta)
  rownames(eta) <- rn
  if(se.fit){
    V <- vcov(object)
    stopifnot(ncol(XD)==ncol(V))
  }
  
  if(type=="response") {
    exp.eta <- exp(eta)
    sum.exp.eta <- rowSums(exp.eta)
    p <- exp.eta/sum.exp.eta
    
    if(se.fit){
      p.long <- as.vector(t(p))
      s <- rep(1:nrow(X),each=nrow(D))
      
      wX <- p.long*(XD - rowsum(p.long*XD,s)[s,,drop=FALSE])
      se.p.long <- sqrt(rowSums(wX * (wX %*% V)))
      se.p <- rspmat(se.p.long)
      rownames(se.p) <- rownames(p)
      if(is.null(na.act))
        list(fit=p,se.fit=se.p)
      else
        list(fit=napredict(na.act,p),
             se.fit=napredict(na.act,se.p))
    }
    else {
      if(is.null(na.act)) p
      else napredict(na.act,p)
    }
  }
  else if(se.fit) {
    se.eta <- sqrt(rowSums(XD * (XD %*% V)))
    se.eta <- rspmat(se.eta)
    eta <- eta[,-1,drop=FALSE]
    se.eta <- se.eta[,-1,drop=FALSE]
    if(is.null(na.act))
        list(fit=eta,se.fit=se.eta) 
    else
      list(fit=napredict(na.act,eta),
           se.fit=napredict(na.act,se.eta))
  }
  else {
      eta <- eta[,-1,drop=FALSE]
      if(is.null(na.act)) eta
      else napredict(na.act,eta)
  }
}
```

Reproducible example of what I would like to achieve:

```
# data=SARS-CoV2 coronavirus variants (variant) through time (collection_date_num)
# in India, count=actual count (nr of sequenced genomes)
dat = read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/u27cn44p5srievq/dat.csv?dl=1")
dat$collection_date = as.Date(dat$collection_date)
dat$collection_date_num = as.numeric(dat$collection_date) # numeric version of date, to convert back to date: as.Date(dat$collection_date_num, origin="1970-01-01")
dat$variant = factor(dat$variant)

# 1. multinom::net multinomial fit ####
library(nnet)
library(splines)
set.seed(1)
fit_nnet = nnet::multinom(variant ~ ns(collection_date_num, df=2), 
                          weights=count, data=dat)
summary(fit_nnet)

# 2. predicted probabilities & 95% CLs at maximum date calculated using emmeans: works, but slow for large models ####
library(emmeans)
multinom_emmeans = emmeans(fit_nnet, ~ variant,  
                       mode = "prob",
                       at=list(collection_date_num = 
                                 max(dat$collection_date_num)))
multinom_emmeans
# variant               prob       SE df lower.CL upper.CL
# Alpha             0.00e+00 0.00e+00 33 0.00e+00 0.00e+00
# Beta              0.00e+00 0.00e+00 33 0.00e+00 0.00e+00
# Delta             7.73e-06 1.17e-06 33 5.34e-06 1.01e-05
# Omicron (BA.1)    1.82e-04 6.42e-05 33 5.14e-05 3.13e-04
# Omicron (BA.2)    1.76e-01 7.45e-03 33 1.61e-01 1.91e-01
# Omicron (BA.2.74) 9.03e-02 7.98e-03 33 7.41e-02 1.07e-01
# Omicron (BA.2.75) 1.68e-01 1.90e-02 33 1.30e-01 2.07e-01
# Omicron (BA.2.76) 2.89e-01 1.35e-02 33 2.62e-01 3.16e-01
# Omicron (BA.3)    1.34e-02 2.10e-03 33 9.10e-03 1.76e-02
# Omicron (BA.4)    1.67e-02 2.47e-03 33 1.17e-02 2.17e-02
# Omicron (BA.5)    2.03e-01 1.08e-02 33 1.81e-01 2.25e-01
# Other             4.23e-02 3.15e-03 33 3.59e-02 4.87e-02
#
# Confidence level used: 0.95 


# 3. predicted probabilities & 95% CLs at maximum date calculated using marginaleffects: does not work because of lack of a predict.multinom method supporting type="link" ####

library(marginaleffects)
multinom_preds_marginaleffects = predictions(fit_nnet,
                                         newdata = datagrid(collection_date_num = 
                                                              max(dat$collection_date_num)),
                                         type="link", # not supported by predict.multinom
                                         transform_post = insight::link_inverse(fit_nnet))
# Error: The `type` argument for models of class `multinom` must be an element of: probs
# PS: desired output should match emmeans output above
```

Comment: You could try `AssignInNamespace`, see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67182540/13513328)

Comment: My memory is that the spell can only be cast with `assignInNamespace`

Comment: What is in `data_agbyweek1$collection_date_num`? Can you share that?

Comment: @Kat sorry that should have been dat$collection_date_num

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way to redefine a method in a package is to use `assignInNamespace`. However, assuming this is intended to be part of another package that will eventually be made public, it's a bit rude since you're trampling over someone else's code. In particular, if you intend to put it on CRAN, you might run into issues with convincing the CRAN reviewers that it's ok.

A better solution would be to create a wrapper method that calls the original method. For this you'll also need to create a wrapper `multinom` function, so that the correct package namespace is found. A sketch implementation is shown below.

```r
multinom <- function(...)
{
    nnet::multinom(...)
}

# this is the link function for multinomial
# = generalized logit
inverse_softMax <- function(mu) {
  log_mu <- log(mu)
  return(sweep(log_mu, 1, STATS=rowMeans(log_mu), FUN="-")) # we let the log(odds) sum to zero - these predictions are referred to as type="latent" in the emmeans package
}

predict.multinom <- function(object, newdata, type=c("probs", "response", "latent", "link") # probs==response, latent==link
{
    type <- match.arg(type)
    if (type == "probs"|type == "response")
        return(nnet:::predict.multinom(object, newdata, type="probs"))

    mu <- nnet:::predict.multinom(object, newdata, type="probs")
    return(inverse_softMax(mu))

}
```